# Checking type in stack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this, I've spent hours researching.

I have an expression in postfix form, ex: 5 6 7 * + 1 -
This is coming from a UITextField , and what I am trying to figure out is how to iterate over that expression and differentiate the integers from the operators(* + -).

Is there some sort of parse method? Using this doesn't work, I just get "Int is not a subtype of Character":

```
for token in expression {
    if token is Int {
      ...
```

Driving me insane, does somebody know the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Strings aren't streams of mixed types, they're streams Characters.  Everything you iterate over is a character, so you have to actually parse around and create your own types to pull values out.

Comment: I guess I don't really know how to do this, should I try something in my knowledge range? Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Is tokens a String? If so you could do something like

```
var tokens : String[] = ["1","x","2","3","y"]
var ints = tokens.map({t in t.toInt()}).filter({t in t != nil}).map({t in t!})
```

or if you just want to filter

```
tokens.filter({t in t.toInt() != nil})
```

or with your if

```
for t in tokens {
    if t.toInt() {
        println(t)
    }  
}
```

if it is about the splitting

```
var tokens : String[] = "1 2 x y 3 z".componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```

Comment: Well token is referring to each character in the string, so I end up with a bunch of characters that I need to determine whether they're integers or operators

Comment: so the test would look like `String(c).toInt()`

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, still getting errors.

        `if String(token).toInt() {
            stack.push(token)
        }`

It's telling me it can't convert character to int when I need to push it onto the stack.

Comment: **View Controller** - http://pastebin.com/qWfWHWEv
**postfix** - http://pastebin.com/7rqUcyc7

This compiles but my evaluation answer is = VC16PostfixEvaluator (no clue why, should be a number)

Comment: with something executable i meant something like `for token in "H1e2l3l4o5" {
 if String(token).toInt() {
  println(token)
 }
}`

Comment: I figured out it's converting the operators "+ and -" to the integer 0. Not sure how to bypass this.

Comment: strange things the apple guys do. what about testing explicitely for it beforehand?

Comment: Yeah I can't get that to work either. I added conditions like `token != "+"` but they're passing through even if the token is "+" and I'm getting the error can't unwrap optional when it tries to convert that to an integer even though it shouldn't be because it should be failing that check.

Comment: maybe the following is working too `for token in "H1e2l3l4o5+-*/".unicodeScalars {
 if token.isDigit() {
  println(token)
 }
}`

Comment: Wow I finally got it working! For some reason swapping the checks worked. Instead of checking `token != "+"`, checking `token == "+"` and swapping the if contents around worked for me! I got a number to show up instead of the stack name itself. Thanks for all the help, I wish I could give rep or upvote but I'm new and don't have enough points myself. :[ Thanks again!